# MSSQL Sum with Case Query Error

Tags: sql-server

I have been trying to complete the below query however I cant seem to get it to work.

I wonder if anyone can see sometihng obvious that I am doing wrong?

MSSQL Server 2012.

I have tested the joins and some of the sub queries as you can see from the query it self and they work fine.

Any ideas?

```
SELECT b.CLIENT_NAME
  ,e.VARIABLE_NAME
  --,[TOTAL]
  --,AVG(a.TOTAL) AS [Total KPI]
   --, (SUM(d.WEEK1_NET)+SUM(d.WEEK2_NET)+SUM(d.WEEK3_NET)+SUM(d.WEEK4_NET))AS [Net Sales]
  ,SUM(
case 
  when a.GRAPH_ID =  1 then 100/(SUM(d.WEEK1_NET)+SUM(d.WEEK2_NET)+SUM(d.WEEK3_NET)+SUM(d.WEEK4_NET))*SUM(a.TOTAL) 
  when a.GRAPH_ID =  2 then 100/ (SUM(d.WEEK1_GROSS)+SUM(d.WEEK2_GROSS)+SUM(d.WEEK3_GROSS)+SUM(d.WEEK4_GROSS))*SUM(a.TOTAL)

  else AVG(a.TOTAL) 
end) AS Project_KPI 
FROM [MMAUDIT].[dbo].[MMA_KPIVAR_DAT] AS a

LEFT JOIN MMA_CLIENT_MST AS b
ON a.CLIENT_ID= b.CLIENT_ID

LEFT JOIN MMA_SITE_MST AS c
ON a.CLIENT_ID= c.CLIENT_ID
AND a.SITE_ID= c.SITE_ID

LEFT JOIN MMA_SALESPERF_DAT AS d
ON a.CLIENT_ID= d.CLIENT_ID
AND a.SITE_ID= d.SITE_ID
AND a.AUDIT_DATE= d.AUDIT_DATE

LEFT JOIN MMA_KPIVAR_MST As e
ON a.CLIENT_ID= e.CLIENT_ID
AND a.CHART_ID=e.CHART_ID
AND a.GRAPH_ID= e.GRAPH_ID
AND a.VARIABLE_ID= e.VARIABLE_ID

WHERE a.CLIENT_ID= 18
AND a.AUDIT_DATE BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-07-01'
--AND a.GRAPH_ID IN (3,4,5,6)
GROUP BY b.CLIENT_NAME
  ,e.VARIABLE_NAME
  --,[TOTAL]'
```

Thank you John

Comment: what are you expecting? what errors do you get and throw in some sample data too :)

Comment: Sorry just noticed I missed off the error: Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery. I'm looking to group the total variables together by client currently they are all by site. I can sum the total up no problem however what I'm trying to achive is a sum with variables e.g if the variable is 1 it calculates it by net sales.

Comment: Just to be clear on the calculation part if Net Sales was 10,000 and a Variable Name had a value of 10. Then the calculation I would do to get the percentage would be 100 / 10000 *10 = 0.1%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have nested SUMs or other aggregates. A simple example is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/88982/4).

```
SUM(
case 
  when a.GRAPH_ID =  1 then 100/(SUM(d.WEEK1_NET)+SUM(d.WEEK2_NET)+SUM(d.WEEK3_NET)+SUM(d.WEEK4_NET))*SUM(a.TOTAL) 
  when a.GRAPH_ID =  2 then 100/ (SUM(d.WEEK1_GROSS)+SUM(d.WEEK2_GROSS)+SUM(d.WEEK3_GROSS)+SUM(d.WEEK4_GROSS))*SUM(a.TOTAL)

  else AVG(a.TOTAL) 
end)
```

is a problem as it nests SUM with both SUM and AVG and the calculation is ambiguous. The easiest fix it to do you inner SUMs: SUM(d.WEEK1_NET) etc in a subquery and then use the values in the case statement in the main query.